# How call a Modal of another Modal

Tags: swift, modalviewcontroller

I know there are other topics on this but I can't seem to find out how to implement it.

I have an app that uses only xibs, no storyboards.

I have a modal with a list of items and I need to show another modal with the details of the selected item.

The error found is that the Modal Detail is being opened below the Modal List, requiring a new user click

Below the code to open the Item List

```
let modalViewController = DependenteListaViewController()
modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Below the code to open the Item Detail

```
let modalViewController = DetailViewController ()
modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
present (modalViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

What is the correct way to call a modal of another modal?

Comment: Whenever you're about to use nesting modals: don't.

Comment: You can't present a modal while another modal is presented. Make the `DependenteListaViewController` on a `UINavigationController` and present the navigation controller, then push `DetailViewController`. Or dismiss the first modal and present the next.

Answer (score 0):

To present a modal above another modal properly you should:

1. Get the view controller that presented the first modal
2. Use that view controller to present the second modal

That way the original presenting view controller will present the second modal above the first.

**Swift**

```
firstModalVC.presentingViewController.present(secondModalVC)
```