# In .NET Maui for iOS, can you display an alert from a community Popup?

Tags: ios, alert, maui

I have a community toolkit popup (toolkit:Popup) that asks a question on a button press.

```
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2022/xaml/maui"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"             
         x:Class="PinPopUp">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Button x:Name="btnRate" Text="Rate" FontSize="12" Clicked="btnRate_Clicked" 
            VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="8" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

with this code behind:

```
private async void btnRate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {     
        bool answer = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Rating", message, "Yes", "No");
        if (answer)
        {         
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Submitting...", result, "OK");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(ex);
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Oops!", "There was an error rating this shop! =(", "OK");
    }
}
```

This works fine on Android, but on iOS once it hits the line to display the first alert, the code execution just returns to form and nothing appears. You can click the button repeatedly.

If it matters the Popup is called by a ContentView not a ContentPage.

I feel like the alert is appearing somewhere its just not visible on the screen, maybe behind something. Is there a way to ensure it is in front of everything?

Comment: Pseudo code is perfect when you try to explain concept to someone, but terrible when describing problems.

Comment: It may require custom code on ios, to get it to appear on top. At the native level: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70167311/199364. Doing this on Maui requires getting at `PlatformView`; look for examples of maui platform-specific handler.

Comment: I face the same issue when calling the alert from blazor webview in the Maui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write Platform code to make it. I make a small demo. You could have a try.

In Project folder, create a new **partial** class, let's call it DisplayAlertService:

```
namespace CommunityPopup75242427
{
    public partial class DisplayAlertService
    {
        public partial void DisplayAlert();
    }
}
```

Then creat another partial class in **Platforms/iOS** folder, called it DisplayAlertService also. Pay attention to the namespace should be the same as above file:

```
namespace CommunityPopup75242427
{
    public partial class DisplayAlertService
    {
        public partial void DisplayAlert()
        {

            var okCancelAlertController = UIAlertController.Create("Alert Title", "Choose from two buttons", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

            //Add Actions
            okCancelAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, alert => Console.WriteLine("Okay was clicked")));             
            okCancelAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, alert => Console.WriteLine("Cancel was clicked")));
            UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();window.RootViewController.PresentedViewController.PresentViewController(okCancelAlertController, true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in popup, you could invoke it using a button clicked for example:

```
async void mybutton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        var d = new DisplayAlertService();
        d.DisplayAlert();
    });
}
```

For more info, you could refer to:

1.[How To Write Platform-Specific Code in .NET MAUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsO6pXz0umc) and [MauiPlatformCodeSample code](https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiPlatformCodeSample).

2.[Displaying Alerts in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/alerts).

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with **App.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch**.
It works both on Android and iOS.

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
{
     bool answer = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Rating", "your message", "Yes", "No");
     if (answer)
        {
             // do it
        }

});
```

[image: Android]

[image: iOS]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It did not work on iOS. Remember my button is on a Popup and the alert is being called from the Popup. I feel like the alert is appearing somewhere its just not visible on the screen, maybe behind something.

Answer (score 0):

Your DisplayAlert call above should indeed be good for both Android and iOS; the only thing that might be in the way of you catching the response might be that iOS really recquires it to be running on the main ui thread. Maybe try and encompasse your asynchronous code inside this:

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    bool answer = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Rating", message, "Yes", "No");
    if (answer)
    {         
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Submitting...", result, "OK");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it's the same result.

Comment: That's a shame, sorry then.