DisplayAlert not displayed if the page is not the AppShell
In my NET8 MAUI app, I display a login page if required, using this code.
if (settings.IsPasswordRequired)
{
    var page = services.GetService<LoginPage>();
    MainPage = page;
}
else
{
    MainPage = new AppShell();
}

In the LoginPage I want to ask the user if he wants to use the biometrics. So, after the successful login, I have this code
private async void Vm_LoginCompleted(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    settings.IsPasswordRequired = true;

    var isAvailable = await IsBiometricAvailable();
    if (isAvailable && !settings.UseBiometric)
    {
        if (await DisplayAlert("Biometric login", 
                  "Enable the login with biometric?", "Yes", "No"))
            settings.UseBiometric = true;
    }

    GotoMainPage();
}

The alert is correctly displayed in Windows and Android but not in iOS. Basically, the app is waiting for the user to select a choice but the alert is not visible.
How can I fix this issue?

Check the required permissions NSFaceIDUsageDescription on Info.plist, and  note that, iOS requests for a permission single time only, if you success before try to reinstall the app.

The problem is related to DisplayAlert not the biometrics.

What is the results if you comment(deactivate) all codes in **Vm_LoginCompleted(object ** method and try to DisplayAlert with a simple text Welcome only

Have you tried App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(...)? Or you may try  native way like https://stackoverflow.com/a/75259922/20118901
